# Synonymes exacts

Tags: synonymes

Quand j'étais à l'école obligatoire, mon professeur de français avait défié quiconque dans la classe de trouver deux mots ayant une racine différente mais totalement identiques d'un point de vue sens (des synonymes parfaits en quelque sorte).
Dans **chaque** contexte où un mot peut être utilisé, il doit pouvoir être remplacé par l'autre de manière transparente (et vice-versa).

Nous n'avions pas été capable de trouver de telles paires de mots, à chaque fois le professeur trouvant au moins un exemple où le remplacement d'un mot par l'autre produisait une phrase dont le sens était légèrement altéré.

Est-ce qu'une telle paire de mots existe dans la langue française ?

Comment: Le problème est que la langue français est riche en synonyme et en nuances. Donc s'il y a plusieurs mots qui ont le même sens, ils y aura normalement une nuance (sinon, il n'y aurait pas 2 mots...). Aussi, la question est trop large pour y répondre...

Comment: Ça m'étonnerait beaucoup, la langue française est connue pour être parmi les plus précises au monde et chaque mot a son propre sens.

Comment: @Random Pourquoi devraient-ils forcément avoir une nuance ? N'est-ce pas possible que deux mots totalement similaires aient pu survivre à travers l'évolution de la langue ?

Comment: Comme tu le dis, il faut "survivre"... Mais pourquoi garder deux mots s'ils veulent dire la même chose ? La flemmingite de l'homme empêche cela, on ne va pas s'encombrer avec un mot inutile, donc il disparaîtra avec le temps...

Answer (score 2):

> *Zeus* et *Jupiter*,

... des mots particuliers certes, mais des mots quand même, et avec eux toute la cohorte des dieux romanisés.

Même si Jupiter était inconnu des Grecs, on peut inter-changer les noms : l'intelligibilité de la phrase est inchangée, on ne désigne qu'une et un seule entité... qui à l'éternité devant elle pour s'amuser de nos furtifs jeux littéraires !

---

***AJOUT***

Il y a un domaine où le synonyme 'absolu' est monnaie courante : *la botanique*, science qui nomme et classifie en latin, à travers toutes les langues à la surface de notre planète.

Ainsi une plante a son nom en latin et au moins un nom local dans chaque langue où elle est étudié, et dans cette langue, chaque région, chaque province donne souvent un nom différent selon l'origine de son patois originel.

> ***Renoncule***, Ranunculus : grenouillette, fleur de l'impatience, gobet du diable à cause de ses propriétés toxiques.

Chaque sous-espèce a un nom latin et un nom vulgaire associé.

---

***P.S.*** : Peut-être dans un contexte médical

> - ***Motilité*** qui est le synonyme médical de ***mobilité*** pour ce qui concerne le mouvement propre d'un organe.

Est un synonyme exact pour une articulation ou pour tout ce qui concerne les mouvements de deux organes en relation, moins pour les mouvements que peut faire un seul organe tel l'estomac.

> - Nos anciennes ***dépendances*** se transforment en ***addictions*** sous la pression anglo-saxone.

---

***P.S. 2*** - Les variantes orthographiques répondent à la question :

*[orichalque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/orichalque#fr) = [aurichalque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aurichalque#fr)*

Quel est l'intérêt de savoir qu'un mot peut s'écrire de deux façons différentes pour le qualifier de synonyme exact ?

Dans l'exemple trouvé ils se prononcent pareille : on découvre un ***synonyme homonyme***...
... pas de quoi faire une déclaration à l'Académie française pour relever un doublon typographique !

... Bon,j'arrête de tondre les œufs.

Comment: Dans la question, le professeur donnait un contre-exemple où on ne pouvait pas les interchanger. Et ici, on ne peut pas voir Zeus avec un télescope... ( je vais chercher trop loin peut-être ? :) )

Comment: @Random -- Oui et non : le sens des mots est variable selon le contexte, et selon les acceptions qu'il supporte. Peu de mots sont univoques, beaucoup on des double sens... l'argot d'origine régionale, maghrébine, italienne, espagnole ... donne 'mille' synonymes pour le même objet. Si la phrase parle des dieux, Zeus = Jupiter (même si les austères du sens diront que seul un romain peut la formuler), sinon il y aura toujours moyen de *chicoter* (origine parmi les moignons d'arbres)... néologisme synonyme de *chicaner* (origine défense militaire).

Comment: @cl-r Alors dans ce cas tous les synonymes peuvent être une réponse à cette questions, parce que pour être des synonymes il faut qu'ils partagent au moins une définition en commun. Donc si on est prêt à ignorer certains des sens des mots, tous les synonymes marchent.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - Encore une fois, oui et non : deux mots peuvent être synonymes, mais induire une nuance : *gourmet* a plus une notion de qualité (autres synonyme *gastronome*) et *gourmand* avec une notion de quantité (autre synonymes *goinfre, glouton*). Mais tous les deux ont un rapport à la nourriture, à des êtres qui apprécient la bonne cuisine, à la notion de plaisir de la table. On peut être un gourmet excessif (reprendre 15 fois du caviar) et un gourmand sélectif  (reprendre 15 fois du caviar). Plusieurs synonymes pour un mot, autant de nuances pour qu'ils se rencontrent ou s'éloignent.

Comment: Une traduction n'est pas un synonyme. De la même manière Zeus et Jupiter ne peuvent pas être considérés comme des synonymes complet, à cause du point soulevé par @Random. Ce que la question pose, c'est l'existance de synonyme sur tous les sens d'une paire de mot, pas juste celle des synonyme en général.

Comment: @MakorDal - En français Zeus et Jupiter représentent le même dieu mythologique, Zeus et Jupiter son français à part entière : un a des parents grecs, l'autre des parents latins mais on ne peut traduire du français Zeus en Jupiter, ni l'inverse, il est français avec deux noms (et donc synonymes) il s'écrit autrement (et souvent avec synonyme) dans d'autres langues. Pour les fleurs même principe de synonyme lié cette fois aux régions ou aux origines patoisantes acceptée par tous.

Comment: @cl-r mais du coup, même avec ce raisonnement, on peut trouver une phrase où ils ne sont pas interchangeables : « Zeus est un dieu Grec », on ne peut pas remplacer par "Jupiter" (qui est Romain). Il y a bien une différence entre les deux... :D

Comment: @Random - Donner deux entrées du dictionnaire avec la même définition n'est pas la définition du synonyme, mais de l'identité. On doit pouvoir en trouver dans le tout jargon technique ou scientifique (Cf mon P.S.).

Comment: +1 pour la piste du contexte médical car il doit y en avoir un paquet vu que les vrais termes médicaux ont souvent des noms courants correspondants, comme ictère/cholémie = jaunisse. (mais même si j’ai tort, j’en ferai pas un ictère, quand même !)

Comment: @PapaPoule ... quoique "J'ai peur que on papier peint *jaunisse*" fasse tiquer notre professeur de français tatillonnesque, peut-être habité par les fantômes du Père Ubu et de Kafka?

Comment: Après les modifications : une seconde orthographe ne constitue pas un synonyme, une traduction ne constitue pas une synonyme et la question de base demande à ce que le synonyme soit applicable à chaque acception des deux mots. D'où un -1

Answer (score 2):

L’emprunt et une réalité linguistique particulière peuvent créer une concurrence. Par exemple, si la question s'était posée dans une classe au [Québec](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871310), on aurait pu aisément identifier la *toast* et la *rôtie* pour la tranche de *pain grillée* ; non seulement interchangeables mais aussi de même genre grammatical. Ailleurs la *rôtie* est [vieillie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%B4tie) (ou régionale) et on a le [*toast*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toast/78261?q=toast#77339) au masculin pour cette même tranche de pain grillée (et la *proposition de boire à la santé*, masculin partout, *porter un toast*).

L'étymologie diffère assurément. La/le [*toast*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toast) (pain), de la [*tostee*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/254246) (de *tostare*, sur *tostus* de *torreo* : dessécher, griller) en français (13<sup>e</sup>) prêtée à la langue anglaise, puis réempruntée pour la tranche de pain au 19<sup>e</sup>. Et la [*rôtie*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%B4tie) (*rostie*, 13<sup>e</sup>), le participe passé de *rôtir*, un [germanisme](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/223704), de *raustjan* « rôtir », de l'ancien haut allemand *rôsten*, allemand *rösten*, moyen néerlandais *roosten* (*TLFi*). Ça répond aux critères de la question mais strictement en français québécois ; quoique la concurrence d'autres emprunts avec des mots en usage soit possible et constitue peut-être une piste de solution. J'ai pensé aussi aux canneberges et aux [*atocas*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/atoca/6128?q=atoca#6107) ([iroquoien](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873045)), mais ces derniers pas très usuels avec le jus...

Comment: Toast a surtout pour acception actuelle : "lever son verre"... même si l'on lève son verre avec un morceau de pain grillé ! Donc, en chinoisant on peut toujours démolir un synonyme, mais celui-ci est très bien trouvé, donc +1, car il a synonymie dans un contexte... ce qui peut faire penser que la question du professeur est en soit une aberration... peut-être une démonstration par l'absurde que l'apparente complexité du français révèle une précision qui permet aux poètes de suggérer l'indicible :)

Comment: @cl-r Merci, sans doute, et je suis plutôt d'accord, un Eldorado ; la question est une réflexion sur la concurrence sémantique.

Comment: ***Concurrence sémantique*** ? Y a-t-il un marché des mots ? Une prime au plus offrant ? Les mots du Veau d'Or en guerre de suprématie contre ceux de Diogène ou de Socrate ? Une valorisation de chaque lettres ??? -  Naïf et me tenant à distance des sorbonicoles rabelaisiens que les temps modernes ont transformés en 'méthodologistes' objectivistes, j'essaye de leur accorder une part d'*être* pour en réaliser le sens et rechercher dans leur sonorité des résonances poétiques ! L'écrit fait travailler les yeux et entraîne le mental (et son diable d'ego), les oreilles murmurent à la conscience :)

Comment: @cl-r Votre commentaire est excellent. Je n'ai aucun agenda ni n'essaye de montrer quoi que ce soit de la langue. Je veux le maximum d'informations, présentées le plus justement possible dans le français le plus clair possible, et s'appuyant sur les traditions propres à la langue française. L'abstraction n'est qu'un outil pour manipuler les concepts, on ne peut s'exprimer que par métaphore ; je refuse de m'en passer, et je signe - ;-)

Comment: ... eh bien... continuons ainsi !!!

Comment: Qui serai-je pour blâmer quelqu'un ? Mettre la sémantique en *concurrence*, c'est laisser la haute finance imposer son vocabulaire et sa façon de penser au français, et donc le priver de la poésie qui met les mots en *concordance* ; de même la psychologie parle de *résilience*, terme technique destiné aux objets pour oblitérer la subjectivité singulière d'un être vivant face aux chocs de la vie. Peut-être suis-je un peu chatouilleux sur ces mots, avec des réactions qui ne trouvent pas toujours la formulation exacte, l'image adéquate ou plutôt la métaphore qui vous est chère :)

Comment: De ce fait, "les sorbonicoles rabelaisiens" est une expression passée de mode depuis bien longtemps pour exprimer que certains étudiants ou doctes personnes arrivent a étouffer le rire de Rabelais sous de verbeuses, inintéressantes (voire incompréhensibles) formules.

Answer (score 1):

C'est certainement impossible ou très difficile à trouver dans les mots d'usage courant, à cause des raisons évoquées, et notamment:

- des expressions (centrées sur un mot particulier);
- de l'usage qui dérive naturellement, et qui fait glisser le sens du propre au figuré, et enrichit d'autres usages.

En revanche, pour des mots d'usage plus rare, très précis (scientifiques, techniques et dans des matières professionnelles), et qui ne sont pas (ou plus rarement) soumis aux phénomènes précédents, on en trouve.

Il y a également le cas des mots du patois ou d'origine de plusieurs régions.

Ou les mots d'origine grecque et leur équivalent d'origine latine, idem avec les langues européennes.

Ou les marques utilisées comme nom générique.

logement = habitation.

contrainte = obligation.

frigo = réfrigérateur.

Comment: Obligation à un sens financier que n'a pas contrainte. Et, sans dictionnaire sous la main, je suis presque sûr que l'on peut trouver des acceptions différentes à logement et habitation. (a vérifier)

Comment: concernant frigo et réfrigérateur, il y a tout de même une différence de langage. Frigo est familier, Réfrigérateur est (très) soutenu. :)

Comment: En effet, la piste des marques devenus des noms communs semble la plus probante: fax=télécopieur, zeppelin=dirigeable, ...

Comment: @MakorDal En effet, un logement peut aussi être une cavité dans une pièce mécanique.

Comment: @Random Bien qu'ils diffèrent de registres de langue, ça n'était pas une contrainte imposée par le problème original.

Comment: @Spotted Je peux donner 2 exemples où on ne peut pas interchanger : "Wesh, vas-y gros, t'as mis les bibines au frigo pour la teuf ?", et "Je ne pense point que c'eusse une bonne idée de garder le vin au réfrigérateur, ce mêt millésimé s'en trouve moins goûtu et n'est point apprécié à sa juste valeur, qu'en pensez vous très chère ?"... :)

Comment: Pour rappel, la marque c'est Frigidaire, frigo est une version écourtée d'"armoire frigorifique". Ce qui rentre correctement dans la seconde phrase, n'est-ce pas ?